# Qt for Android on OpenSuse 13.2

Tags: java, android, qt, ant

I've just upgraded from Opensuse 13.1 to 13.2 and can no longer get my Qt development for android to work correctly. My investigation leads me to believe that it's more of an android development issue (ant) than anything to do with Qt.

I'm getting the error below while trying to deploy the example projects. I've found that it might be tied to missing xml-apis package, possible the xml-commons packages should provide this functionality but they don't seem to.

I'm not at all familiar with Java and have been stuck on this for a while now. Any suggestions appreciated.

```
22:46:33: Starting: "/home/bobstaff/Qt/5.3/android_armv7/bin/androiddeployqt" --input /home/bobstaff/Qt/Examples/Qt-5.3/quick/scenegraph/build-openglunderqml-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_3_2-Debug/android-libopenglunderqml.so-deployment-settings.json --output /home/bobstaff/Qt/Examples/Qt-5.3/quick/scenegraph/build-openglunderqml-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_3_2-Debug/android-build --deployment bundled --install --ant /usr/bin/ant --android-platform android-21 --jdk /usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk --device 10.1.2.5:5555
22:46:33: Pulling files necessary for debugging.
22:46:33: Package deploy: Running command '/home/bobstaff/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 10.1.2.5:5555 pull /system/bin/app_process /home/bobstaff/Qt/Examples/Qt-5.3/quick/scenegraph/build-openglunderqml-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_3_2-Debug/app_process'.
22:46:33: Package deploy: Running command '/home/bobstaff/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 10.1.2.5:5555 pull /system/lib/libc.so /home/bobstaff/Qt/Examples/Qt-5.3/quick/scenegraph/build-openglunderqml-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_3_2-Debug/libc.so'.

BUILD FAILED
/home/bobstaff/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:407: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.startDocumentParsing(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:466)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:513)
    at com.android.ant.GetTypeTask.execute(GetTypeTask.java:85)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 40 more

Total time: 0 seconds
Generating Android Package
  Input file: /home/bobstaff/Qt/Examples/Qt-5.3/quick/scenegraph/build-openglunderqml-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_3_2-Debug/android-libopenglunderqml.so-deployment-settings.json
  Output directory: /home/bobstaff/Qt/Examples/Qt-5.3/quick/scenegraph/build-openglunderqml-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_3_2-Debug/android-build
  Application binary: /home/bobstaff/Qt/Examples/Qt-5.3/quick/scenegraph/build-openglunderqml-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_3_2-Debug/libopenglunderqml.so
  Android build platform: android-21
  Install to device: 10.1.2.5:5555
Buildfile: /home/bobstaff/Qt/Examples/Qt-5.3/quick/scenegraph/build-openglunderqml-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_3_2-Debug/android-build/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.5
 [checkenv] Installed at /home/bobstaff/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: QtApp
Building the android package failed!
  -- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
22:46:36: The process "/home/bobstaff/Qt/5.3/android_armv7/bin/androiddeployqt" exited with code 14.
Error while building/deploying project openglunderqml (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.3.2))
When executing step "Deploy to Android device"
22:46:36: Elapsed time: 00:04.
```

Comment: I read it is recommended to use the Oracle JDK for android developement. You can try with it. https://fr.opensuse.org/SDB:Installer_Java#Installer_Java_d.27Oracle

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same error with the Oracle JDK

Answer (score 6):

I solved the same problem by removing 'xml-commons', 'xml-commons-jaxp-1.3-apis' using opensuse 13.2 software manager and installing 'xerces-j2', 'xerces-j2-xml-apis', 'xerces-j2-xml-resolver' and my project reports BUILD SUCCESSFUL.

**Complete steps for clarifying:**

1. open "Software Management" from "Yast2" control centre.
2. search for "xml-commons".
3. Uncheck 'xml-commons', 'xml-commons-jaxp-1.X-apis' if are
   checked(installed)[note: X stands for any version number], and
   Accept for complete uninstalling that softwares.
4. Now search for 'xerces-j2'.
5. Check(install) 'xerces-j2', 'xerces-j2-xml-apis',
   'xerces-j2-xml-resolver' from result list and Accept for installing
   them or if they are currently checked dont tuch them!


   **that was all of my solution for this problem.**